# Stop chrome top bar bounce on scroll threejs?

Tags: html, css, three.js, joystick, react-three-fiber

I'm facing a issue where I have a joystick control in my website and whenever I move my joystick down chrome either brings the refresh dropdown or chrome top bar bounces and goes in and out fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to fix this problem

```css
body,
Canvas {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```